# Prevent duplicate objects but update quantity in shopping cart ReactJS/NextJS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, local-storage, shopping-cart

Im having touble with a shopping cart in NextJS, I'm trying to update the Cart when someone clicks the "Add to cart" button in the product page. Im using LocalStorage.

```
export const DataContext = createContext();

export const DataProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const initialState = [];
  const [cart, setCart] = useState(initialState);
  const [qty, setQty] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    const cartData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
    if (cartData) {
      setCart(cartData);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (cart !== initialState)
      localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));

  }, [cart]);

  const addToCart = (newProduct) => {
    const ProductExists = cart.find((pr) => pr.item._id === newProduct._id);
    setCart((prev) => [...prev, { item: newProduct, quantity: 1 }]);
    // Here is where I have to solve the problem I think, obviously Im just adding a single product
   
  };


  return (
    <DataContext.Provider value={{ cart, setCart, state, dispatch, addToCart }}>
      {children}
    </DataContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

I hope I made myself clear
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

honestly I suggest you'd have a Map or an Object instead of an array for this reason
it should look like this:

```
/*
 *  {
 *    [productId1]: {
 *      quantity: Number,
 *      ...newProduct // All the other product attributes here
 *    }
 *  }
 */

const addToCart = (newProduct) => {
  const prevProduct = cart[newProduct._id];
  const prevQuatity = prevProduct.quantity || 0;
  setCart((prev) => ({
    ...prev,
    [newProduct.Id]: {
      ...newProduct,
      quantity: prevQuatity + 1,
    },
  }));
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but Im a bit noob with react, what does that commented code mean? where should I write it?

Comment: You should not write it anywhere, I was just explaining how the state would look like now, instead of having an array of all the items in the cart, you'd have an object, with the items Ids being the keys, and the value is also an object, carrying all the product details including the quantity :) 
you could just paste the `addToCart` code and it should work

Comment: Just by adding that code it does not work, I surely need to change the initialState but I can't achieve it.

Comment: ah sorry, initial state should just be an empty object, instead of array now

Comment: No problem, also  a "?" is missing where prevProduct?.quantity || 0. Well, that's what a friend told me. But the rest of the code worked for me. Thank you :D

Comment: Great to hear :) hope you have happy coding!